# Moment js giving incorrect week

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, momentjs

**Here's my javascript**

```
dt = moment("2016-01-01");
console.log(dt.week());
```

This gives week as 1

but when I refer to **bootstrap calendar** then it shows week as 53 of last year

[image]

can someone tell which is correct moment or bootstrap calendar? Also why?

PS - datepicker I am using is `ui.bootstrap.datepicker` from https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: The correct answer is that it's week 53 (of 2015) http://www.epochconverter.com/weeks/2016

Comment: I think it is to do with the set locale and what is the 'first' day of the week. moment.locale('en');
console.log(moment.locale()); // should give en

Comment: @PaulThomasGC if week 53 is right answer then how to get correct week information from momentjs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a bit of google search I found that using **isoWeek()** gives correct week number in my case.